# How can I focus the cursor into the test results output area using the keyboard in Jetbrains IDEs?

Tags: intellij-idea, rubymine, jetbrains-ide

I have just run some Rspec tests in Rubymine and I want to use the keyboard to focus on the test results so that I can then jump to the test source code.

Here's the bottom of the IDE window. I want to first focus into the left hand pane so I can choose the correct test, then jump to the right hand pane so I can choose the line to go to. I've tried to use Command-4 to focus on the pane, but it just focuses the tab and not into the actual pane.

What is the correct key combination to do this (or what are the actions called on the keymap so I can assign keys)?

[image: Picture of Rubymine screen]

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not what you asked (and I'd like to know an answer), I did just discover the "Select Failed Test When Finished" option in the Run pane settings (the blue gear in the upper right of the left-hand sub-pane). It selects the first failed test (which puts the output of that test in the right-hand sub-pane) and puts focus in the right-hand sub-pane. So if you always want to do that when a test fails, it might make you happy a lot of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "Tab" button. After that, you could move logs with Up/Down arrows or PageUp/PageDown buttons.

It works on my IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.5.

Answer (score 0):

View -> Tool Windows -> Run

For me, the shortcut would be [Alt+4], and it is displayed in the menu, you will see it. If there's none, go to Keymap settings and configure it.

And yes, this question is old but it's a useful shortcut